# speed and fortitude

Tags: biology, xenobiology, aliens

I want to create an alien that is fast and can run far. I watched a vsauce video that explained that the human's butt is responsible for our ability to run the furthest in the animal kingdom. I am making the alien an interped (goes between 4 legs and 2). Should I give the alien a big butt or should I just make it a bit more back heavy with something like organic armor on its back or does the weight need to be lower?

If this idea is dumb is there any other way to make the alien have fortitude and speed at the same time?

Comment: "(...)our ability to run the furthest in the animal kingdom(...)" two things: 1. the animal able to run the furthest without tiring is the kangaroo, not humans. We are not even 2nd place. Nor 3rd. 2. you've clearly never chased a dog around.

Comment: I think the big butt is a fine idea.  Especially if this were for a TV show because people could see the big butt and appreciate it, and you would not have to mention the fact of the big butt over and over like you will have to for a story.  Not that there is anything wrong with that.

Comment: is the animal a tetrapod? has it evolved from something with a fairly similar physical  form as earth life-froms